# Possible to force CloudFront to sync with entire S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cdn, amazon-cloudfront

I'm using an S3 bucket as the origin or a CloudFront distribution. My understanding is that CloudFront caches files from the origin on an as-needed basis. I'm putting up a demo website and would like to have it cache all the files initially. Rather than waiting for each file to eventually get requested through the normal use of the site, is there a way to force CloudFront to sync everything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is no way to do that as of today. I guess this would not be economical for AWS as they would need to preload your content in all their edge locations.

Furthermore as your backend is S3 you should have no fear for performance and scalability.

Comment: Ok. Regarding your second sentence, won't there be a slight performance hit the first time a file is downloaded? Or is it so slight that I shouldn't give it another thought?

Comment: Under normal conditions, it would be a negligible delay the first time the file is requested.